# search object by Node ID or object id and update item in Ez publish 5 from php

Tags: ezpublish

I want search object by Node ID or object ID  and update items  in Ez publish 5 from php, I research  in google and can`t find valid solution for ez publish 5 ,   can anyone help me and explain how i can do it or  link me some useful tutorial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find a lot of information here for Browsing, finding, viewing: https://doc.ez.no/display/DEVELOPER/Browsing%2C+finding%2C+viewing

When it comes to CRUD, there are plenty of examples here. Those are basically commands that do stuff like creating images, changing data etc. https://github.com/ezsystems/CookbookBundle/tree/master/Command

Other resources: 
- https://doc.ez.no/display/DEVELOPER/Other+recipes
- https://doc.ez.no/display/DEVELOPER/Working+with+Locations
- https://doc.ez.no/display/DEVELOPER/Managing+Content